# Getting "structural error" while converting a Swagger 2.0 file to OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0

Snippet of my code:

```yaml
  insuranceCompanyNbr:
    type: integer
    totalDigits: 6
  invoiceTypeInfo:
    $ref: '#/definitions/invoiceTypeInfo'
  submitterTypeId:
    type: string
```

I get this error:

> Error: Structural error at definitions.InvoiceType.properties.insuranceCompanyNbr.
> should NOT have additional properties.
> additionalProperty: totalDigits

How can I resolve this error?

I tried adding schema at the beginning of the code, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `totalDigits` keyword in OpenAPI - neither in v. 2.0, nor in 3.x. You need to either remove this keyword, or prefix it with `x-` to make it an [extension](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) (that is, arbitrary metadata).